# Just announced MacOS Mojave: what level of support for Metal is required?

Tags: gpu, mojave

The general consensus is that older Macs can run Mojave if they have a graphic card supporting Metal (c.f. [appleinsider](https://appleinsider.com/articles/18/06/05/macos-mojave-will-drop-support-for-some-older-macs-released-before-2012) for example). But Metal-readiness comes in different degrees. Has Apple disclosed what is the lowest bar yet?

Comment: The link in your question lists the minimum Mac models that can run Mojave.  What exactly are you looking for?

Comment: The last line, "Mac Pro (2010 or later with Metal-compatible GPU)", mean it won't work with the graphic card those machines were shipped with. One needs to install a newer one. That's already true for High Sierra and maybe even Sierra, I don't remember.

Comment: The question might be "What is considered to be a 'Metal-compatible GPU'? I've two 2010 Mac Pros I may need to update.

Comment: @Tetsujin iiuc you would need to update the graphic card only. I am in the same boat: I have a 2010 Mac Pro too!

Comment: "update the graphic card only" ... to what, precisely. I think finding a list of 'recommended' cards would be the priority here. I found a 'metal test' app, but it crashes.

Comment: @Tetsujin That's precisely my question! Have you tried GFXBench Metal? It displays a list of all Metal features available on a machine. Available on the Mac App Store.

Comment: Ah - that's what I was looking for, something at least to say "this works with Metal, this doesn't" My 7950 seems to be OK, an older 5770 is OpenGL only.

Answer (score 2):

The article [Apple Outlines Metal-Capable Cards](https://www.macrumors.com/2018/09/24/mojave-2010-2012-mac-pro-metal-graphics-cards/) goes into the detail needed.

From linked article --

> According to Apple, the following graphics cards are known to be
>   Metal-capable and compatible with macOS Mojave on the mid-2010 and
>   mid-2012 Mac Pro models:
>
> - MSI Gaming Radeon RX 560 128-bit 4GB GDDR5
>
>   - SAPPHIRE Radeon PULSE RX 580 8GB GDDR5
>   - SAPPHIRE Radeon HD 7950 Mac Edition
>   - NVIDIA Quadro K5000 for Mac
>   - NVIDIA GeForce GTX 680 Mac Edition

Answer (score 1):

Metal is required to run the OS. Apple has [deprecated OpenGL and OpenCL](https://apple.slashdot.org/story/18/06/05/1719205/apple-deprecates-opengl-and-opencl-in-macos-1014-mojave) and additionally is [now using Metal exclusively to render the GUI](https://www.reddit.com/r/MacOS/comments/8ol6v2/feature_macos_mojave_beta_custom_accent_colours/e07ezse/).

---

If your Mac does not support Metal, the user interface will not be able to run, and as a result Mojave will not boot.

Comment: As stated in my question I knew that. But Metal 1 or 2 for a start?

Comment: If any of the compatible models don't support Metal 2, then I guess it needs Metal 1. If that isn't the case, Metal 2.

Answer (score 0):

From [Metal (API) - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metal_(API)):

> Metal 2 is not a separate API from Metal and is supported by the same hardware. Metal 2 enables more efficient profiling and debugging in Xcode, accelerated machine learning, lower CPU workload, support for virtual reality on macOS, and specificities of the Apple A11 GPU, in particular.